# What is the way in RxJS to keep collecting results from multiple and different http calls independently on when one of those fails?

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest

I've used zip and forkJoin

```
return forkJoin({
  a: this.getA(),
  b: this.getB(),
  c: this.getC()
})
```

the problem is that if one of those calls fails, all the call get cancelled, whereas I'd like to still collect data from the ones which didn't fail
Is making them separately the only way to do it?

Comment: You catchError on each of the input observables, so none of their errors make it to forkJoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you have to **catch the error and treat it correctly in the inner observable**

```
return forkJoin({
  a: this.getA(),
  b: this.getB(),
  c: this.getC().pipe(catchError(error => of(error)))
})

// If getC fails, you would get A and B
```

My question is whether you have to add this treatment only to the last element or to all of them. You will have to try it yourself, please let me know in the comments.

See [HERE](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin#example-3-handling-errors-on-outside) the Example 5: Getting successful results when one inner observable errors